# PostgreSQl - creatdb with shell script

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have a small shell script thats gets triggerd by another script via ssh.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ]
    then
echo "Missing DB Name!"
exit 1
    else 
    PROJECT=$1
fi

createdb -U postgres -T mytemplate -O myuser $PROJECT_dev
```

The problem is that the createdb statement doesent sees the $PROJECT variable. 
It's always empty when the script gets called.

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly brackets to delimit your actual variable:

```
createdb -U postgres -T mytemplate -O myuser ${PROJECT}_dev
```

otherwise, bash thinks the whole "PROJECT_dev" is your variable.